# Typescript and React without modules - cannot find name 'React'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building a React app with typescript within the context of a third-party solution, which means (for reasons that don't matter here), that I can't use modules, and have to rely on typescript namespaces only. I can get all my internal references and dependencies to resolve, but I can't work out how to get typescript to recognise React. My gulp-typescript compilation step always gives multiple errors:

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you need to define or link the dependencies for React

Comment: Indeed @JohnRuddell. That is what I have so far been unable to achieve, since all the examples I can find use modules to define those dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try adding react to the global namespace using a script tag?
https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js

Comment: The problem is telling the typescript compiler about it. The script tag is there, but TS does not know about it.

Comment: Okay, sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
import React = __React;
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be pretty simple. I just needed to add:

```
import * as React from "/libs/react.development";
import * as ReactDOM from "/libs/react-dom.development";
```